Chopping behavior of ADC output
A group parterner of mine is calibrating a board, and the ADC output is somewhat confusing

A closer-up view at one of the 1.5v platforms looks like this

So it seems as if the output has been ceiled near some particular values.
In order to figure out why, I acquired the raw integer output of the ADC and made a histogram

I think the issue occurs near the integers 1936,1968,2000,2032,2048,2064,
each of which have all-zeros in their lowest four bits
011110010000 
011110110000 
011111010000 
011111110000 
100000000000 
100000010000

but I don't have a clue what may lead to this. The closest behavior I have found on EESE is this post, but I don't understand if it is actually a related issue.
I don't have much experience regarding hardware in general, so any advice on how I should proceed to investigate the issue or make modifications to the analog upstream circuit would be helpful.

The following is the raw output of the ADC:
1963 1951 1951 1954 1947 1949 1950 1948 1948 1949 1947 1947 1948 1947 1948 1947 1949 1946 1945 1949 1948 1946 1946 1944 1946 1946 1948 1947 1943 1938 1945 1946 1941 1947 1941 1943 1943 1942 1943 1942 1946 1943 1943 1943 1941 1943 1943 1941 1941 1940 1942 1943 1941 1943 1942 1941 1941 1941 1940 1943 1942 1941 1934 1939 1940 1941 1939 1941 1939 1940 1940 1935 1939 1935 1935 1938 1939 1935 1938 1938 1938 1937 1937 1941 1938 1939 1939 1935 1939 1938 1935 1939 1935 1929 1937 1939 1935 1938 1937 1938 1935 1935 1937 1938 1938 1935 1935 1943 1937 1939 1935 1935 1935 1938 1935 1940 1938 1935 1935 1937 1940 1935 1935 1939 1935 1935 1938 1938 1939 1941 1939 1941 1940 1940 1940 1938 1938 1939 1940 1942 1940 1939 1941 1939 1940 1941 1943 1942 1938 1942 1940 1938 1945 1939 1942 1941 1943 1949 1940 1942 1941 1942 1943 1943 1943 1940 1942 1942 1943 1941 1945 1944 1943 1943 1945 1942 1943 1943 1945 1946 1945 1946 1935 1951 1947 1946 1945 1946 1943 1945 1948 1946 1948 1952 1950 1946 1949 1947 1948 1948 1949 1949 1949 1951 1949 1951 1951 1952 1951 1951 1950 1949 1951 1951 1953 1952 1955 1952 1953 1952 1951 1961 1955 1949 1955 1957 1956 1956 1954 1955 1958 1955 1957 1957 1957 1959 1958 1957 1960 1958 1958 1962 1957 1957 1955 1963 1958 1962 1960 1963 1962 1961 1960 1963 1963 1963 1963 1965 1963 1965 1965 1964 1964 1966 1967 1966 1965 1966 1967 1969 1967 1967 1973 1970 1972 1971 1973 1972 1971 1972 1972 1972 1973 1972 1973 1975 1974 1973 1975 1976 1977 1976 1979 1977 1979 1977 1981 1979 1979 1980 1979 1978 1978 1975 1987 1983 1983 1985 1981 1982 1980 1983 1983 1983 1985 1984 1986 1986 1987 1987 1990 1988 1991 1988 1989 1989 1991 1993 1991 1990 1989 1990 1993 1995 1997 1990 1995 1993 1997 1996 1996 1996 1997 1997 1999 1998 1997 1999 1999 1999 1999 2002 1999 1999 1999 2002 1999 2003 2003 2004 2003 2005 2005 2005 2007 2006 2007 2007 2007 2007 2009 2007 2011 2011 2009 2010 2012 2013 2013 2014 2012 2013 2013 2013 2014 2015 2014 2016 2015 2016 2015 2019 2017 2017 2016 2023 2019 2020 2021 2021 2018 2020 2021 2022 2022 2022 2023 2022 2024 2025 2025 2027 2023 2028 2023 2027 2027 2026 2027 2027 2029 2030 2029 2029 2029 2037 2027 2029 2031 2031 2031 2031 2035 2031 2034 2031 2035 2034 2037 2035 2036 2035 2036 2036 2037 2037 2039 2036 2038 2034 2040 2039 2037 2038 2037 2038 2048 2039 2041 2048 2039 2042 2048 2042 2042 2041 2048 2040 2048 2048 2048 2048 2048 2048 2048 2048 2048 2048 2048 2048 2048 2050 2049 2048 2048 2050 2050 2052 2048 2049 2050 2051 2051 2052 2051 2054 2052 2053 2055 2053 2052 2053 2054 2056 2057 2057 2053 2057 2055 2056 2055 2057 2057 2057 2057 2056 2059 2053 2059 2058 2055 2055 2059 2058 2060 2056 2058 2062 2059 2062 2059 2060 2061 2063 2059 2061 2063 2060 2062 2061 2059 2063 2061 2062 2063 2060 2062 2061 2061 2063 2062 2062 2063 2063 2063 2063 2062 2063 2063 2063 2063 2066 2063 2062 2063 2063 2063 2063 2065 2063 2066 2063 2067 2068 2067 2063 2066 2061 2063 2066 2067 2063 2065 2063 2070 2066 2068 2066 2067 2063 2067 2068 2066 2066 2068 2067 2063 2067 2066 2067 2067 2065 2067 2066 2068 2067 2067 2076 2068 2067 2067 2067 2069 2067 2068 2070 2068 2063 2068 2066 2066 2067 2067 2069 2067 2063 2068 2066 2071 2066 2063 2069 2066 2068 2066 2065 2069 2063 2068 2067 2067 2063 2067 2066 2063 2067 2063 2068 2063 2066 2063 2067 2063 2063 2063 2063 2063 2063 2063 2063 2063 2063 2063 2061 2063 2063 2061 2063 2055 2063 2061 2063 2061 2063 2063 2062 2059 2060 2063 2063 2063 2060 2062 2059 2061 2062 2060 2058 2059 2058 2062 2058 2062 2060 2059 2059 2059 2060 2055 2058 2056 2057 2058 2058 2061 2059 2058 2056 2058 2055 2055 2056 2054 2056 2055 2055 2056 2054 2055 2054 2053 2051 2056 2055 2053 2052 2052 2053 2052 2057 2049 2052 2051 2051 2050 2048 2051 2050 2049 2050 2049 2050 2048 2049 2048 2048 2050 2048 2048 2048 2048 2048 2048 2048 2048 2048 2041 2048 2048 2048 2040 2048 2048 2041 2041 2042 2041 2048 2038 2042 2039 2040 2039 2037 2039 2037 2037 2039 2038 2035 2037 2034 2038 2036 2036 2035 2034 2035 2035 2031 2031 2034 2034 2034 2033 2035 2030 2031 2030 2031 2030 2031 2025 2029 2029 2030 2029 2027 2031 2028 2027 2027 2026 2026 2027 2023 2025 2029 2027 2027 2022 2025 2025 2024 2023 2022 2025 2020 2021 2021 2021 2019 2019 2019 2020 2017 2018 2019 2019 2018 2015 2014 2016 2014 2018 2014 2015 2013 2009 2017 2012 2011 2012 2011 2013 2011 2011 2011 2009 2008 2010 2009 2007 2008 2007 2008 2005 2007 2006 2005 2004 2005 2002 1999 2002 2004 1999 2003 2003 1998 2002 1999 1999 1999 2001 1998 1998 1999 1998 1996 1997 1998 1996 1996 1995 1997 1993 1995 1994 1996 1992 1995 1993 1991 1991 1993 1992 1988 1991 1989 1989 1989 1991 1987 1988 1989 1989 1985 1986 1987 1985 1986 1983 1986 1983 1983 1982 1982 1982 1982 1979 1980 1979 1979 1980 1977 1976 1979 1978 1978 1975 1979 1975 1975 1975 1977 1975 1975 1975 1972 1971 1970 1970 1971 1970 1967 1967 1967 1967 1967 1967 1965 1967 1967 1967 1964 1966 1964 1966 1965 1964 1963 1963 1960 1964 1964 1963 1962 1963 1960 1961 1961 1960 1959 1962 1959 1958 1959 1961 1956 1957 1959 1956 1956 1959 1957 1957 1959 1956 1957 1959 1955 1957 1955 1957 1951 1955 1954 1952 1954 1953 1953 1952 1955 1951 1952 1951 1950 1951 1951 1952 1951 1949 1951 1948 1950 1949 1951 1950 1949 1949 1954 1945 1950 1949 1947 1948 1945 1948 1945 1946 1947 1944 1946 1946 1946 1946 1945 1947 1946 1946 1946 1943 1941 1943 1942 1943 1946 1942 1942 1943 1947 1940 1949 1942 1940 1941 1943 1941 1940 1943 1942 1941 1942 1943 1944 1942 1944 1942 1940 1941 1939 1941 1940 1942 1941 1944 1941 1940 1942 1939 1939 1942 1941 1943 1941 1938 1942 1939 1938 1939 1935 1938 1935 1935 1939 1939 1939 1939 1939 1938 1935 1935 1937 1937 1935 1939 1935 1939 1938 1935 1939 1938 1935 1938 1938 1935 1935 1935 1935 1938 1935 1939 1939 1939 1935 1935 1939 1938 1938 1939 1935 1935 1939 1935 1939 1938 1940 1935 1938 1945 1927 1943 1939 1939 1939 1940 1939 1938 1941 1939 1942 1941 1942 1940 1941 1939 1941 1940 1941 1939 1941 1942 1935 1943 1942 1939 1944 1940 1940 1942 1941 1945 1941 1941 1942 1942 1945 1943 1943 1944 1943 1945 1943 1943 1943 1946 1945 1946 1943 1945 1944 1944 1945 1947 1945 1946 1947 1945 1946 1947 1946 1945 1947 1943 1948 1947 1946 1948 1947 1949 1948 1948 1949 1948 1947 1949 1950 1950 1951 1949 1946 1951 1950 1952 1952 1953 1953 1953 1952 1953 1956 1953 1955 1954 1952 1954 1954 1953 1954 1957 1954 1955 1957 1953 1957 1957 1957 1956 1957 1961 1958 1959 1961 1959 1959 1958 1960 1961 1961 1961 1962 1966 1962 1965 1960 1964 1963 1962 1962 1964 1966 1962 1962 1966 1965 1964 1966 1966 1965 1967 1967 1967 1967 1965 1967 1970 1971 1970 1973 1971 1967 1974 1970 1972 1971 1975 1972 1972 1972 1973 1975 1972 1974 1975 1977 1978 1975 1973 1977 1979 1981 1978 1977 1978 1981 1980 1982 1981 1983 1983 1979 1976 1989 1984 1982 1986 1983 1983 1985 1988 1984 1985 1985 1986 1987 1989 1989 1987 1989 1989 1988 1991 1991 1992 1990 1991 1992 1991 1993 1990 1994 1995 1991 1996 1996 1996 1995 1996 1997 1997 1997 1998 1999 1999 1998 1999 1998 1999 1999 1999 1999 2004 2003 2005 2003 2005 2007 2005 2007 2008 2008 2007 2014 2002 2009 2007 2008 2010 2011 2011 2010 2013 2015 2012 2007 2013 2011 2013 2014 2014 2012 2014 2015 2018 2014 2019 2014 2017 2019 2017 2019 2021 2024 2015 2022 2019 2022 2024 2023 2022 2024 2023 2022 2022 2025 2023 2028 2027 2025 2026 2026 2025 2028 2028 2028 2030 2031 2029 2029 2028 2029 2029 2027 2029 2031 2031 2031 2031 2031 2034 2031 2031 2031 2036 2036 2035 2036 2035 2037 2039 2035 2037 2039 2036 2039 2038 2038 2037 2041 2038 2039 2039 2048 2041 2038 2048 2040 2040 2048 2048 2048 2048 2043 2048 2048 2048 2048 2048 2048 2048 2053 2048 2048 2048 2048 2048 2048 2048 2048 2049 2048 2048 2048 2050 2049 2052 2049 2052 2051 2053 2051 2052 2055 2050 2052 2054 2052 2053 2055 2050 2053 2055 2055 2054 2053 2055 2056 2054 2057 2054 2056 2055 2058 2055 2058 2058 2058 2056 2057 2056 2058 2060 2062 2058 2059 2061 2060 2060 2059 2060 2060 2062 2060 2059 2069 2060 2060 2059 2063 2056 2062 2061 2062 2058 2067 2062 2062 2063 2068 2062 2063 2063 2063 2063 2062 2062 2063 2062 2063 2063 2062 2067 2066 2063 2066 2063 2063 2063 2063 2063 2066 2063 2063 2066 2071 2063 2063 2066 2067 2063 2063 2063 2063 2063 2066 2063 2063 2068 2063 2067 2066 2063 2063 2066 2068 2063 2066 2066 2061 2063 2063 2067 2068 2067 2063 2066 2066 2066 2063 2066 2066 2068 2066 2068 2063 2067 2063 2067 2068 2067 2068 2067 2067 2066 2066 2069 2066 2066 2066 2061 2065 2063 2063 2067 2063 2063 2068 2063 2063 2066 2063 2065 2063 2063 2068 2066 2063 2065 2063 2063 2063 2063 2067 2063 2063 2063 2063 2063 2062 2063 2063 2062 2059 2063 2062 2061 2061 2063 2063 2062 2061 2063 2066 2061 2060 2060 2061 2060 2063 2059 2061 2061 2061 2058 2061 2060 2058 2061 2059 2057 2058 2061 2060 2056 2058 2056 2057 2057 2058 2059 2057 2057 2055 2056 2054 2055 2056 2055 2055 2056 2053 2055 2054 2052 2054 2051 2053 2052 2051 2053 2052 2052 2055 2051 2053 2054 2049 2049 2050 2050 2049 2048 2049 2049 2048 2050 2048 2048 2051 2048 2048 2048 2048 2048 2048 2048 2048 2048 2048 2048 2048 2048 2042 2040 2048 2048 2039 2048 2048 2048 2048 2042 2040 2041 2041 2041 2039 2037 2038 2036 2038 2038 2036 2037 2035 2036 2036 2037 2034 2034 2036 2035 2031 2035 2035 2034 2031 2031 2031 2030 2028 2031 2030 2027 2028 2029 2027 2026 2025 2030 2027 2025 2025 2026 2027 2025 2024 2025 2023 2024 2025 2021 2026 2023 2023 2024 2020 2020 2021 2020 2021 2020 2012 2020 2020 2018 2021 2016 2018 2017 2018 2016 2015 2016 2015 2015 2013 2015 2013 2013 2013 2014 2012 2010 2014 2009 2005 2013 2010 2011 2009 2006 2009 2007 2007 2007 2006 2007 2005 2004 2006 2007 2003 2006 2003 2003 2002 1999 2002 2003 1999 1999 1999 1998 1999 1999 1999 1997 1997 1997 1996 1997 1995 1997 1993 1997 1995 1993 1997 1994 1996 1994 1994 1992 1993 1990 1992 1991 1991 1989 1991 1990 1989 1988 1987 1985 1993 1989 1989 1988 1985 1985 1984 1985 1985 1987 1983 1985 1982 1979 1982 1980 1983 1980 1981 1978 1978 1975 1978 1976 1977 1977 1976 1975 1975 1977 1972 1976 1973 1973 1971 1974 1970 1967 1970 1970 1967 1971 1972 1967 1967 1971 1967 1966 1967 1967 1966 1967 1965 1966 1965 1964 1963 1963 1965 1967 1962 1965 1965 1959 1961 1962 1959 1961 1963 1960 1960 1965 1959 1958 1959 1959 1959 1959 1957 1958 1955 1957 1955 1954 1957 1955 1956 1956 1955 1951 1948 1955 1953 1954 1949 1955 1950 1954 1953 1952 1950 1954 1952 1952 1949 1951 1949 1948 1949 1950 1947 1951 1950 1949 1949 1949 1949 1948 1947 1946 1947 1949 1947 1945 1943 1946 1947 1944 1946 1943 1947 1945 1945 1945 1946 1943 1946 1944 1945 1944 1944 1944 1943 1945 1945 1942 1946 1945 1945 1943 1942 1945 1946 1942 1943 1941 1941 1942 1941 1943 1942 1941 1941 1940 1940 1939 1940 1941 1941 1941 1941 1941 1941 1940 1941 1940 1940 1942 1941 1940 1943 1941 1938 1939 1941 1939 1943 1940 1941 1937 1940 1943 1939 1939 1935 1939 1935 1939 1938 1941 1940 1939 1938 1940 1938 1935 1939 1938 1935 1935 1939 1939 1938 1937 1935 1939 1938 1938 1937 1939 1935 1938 1935 1937 1938 1938 1938 1938 1938 1938 1935 1935 1935 1935 1938 1940 1937 1935 1935 1934 1939 1931 1935 1937 1940 1935 1938 1937 1938 1937 1941 1939 1939 1938 1941 1941 1941 1939 1939 1941 1935 1941 1934 1942 1939 1941 1942 1941 1943 1940 1943 1943 1939 1949 1942 1941 1943 1943 1943 1943 1942 1943 1944 1945 1943 1943 1943 1943 1944 1945 1945 1940 1945 1945 1946 1943 1946 1948 1947 1943 1947 1952 1951 1945 1947 1948 1949 1949 1946 1945 1949 1948 1948 1947 1955 1950 1947 1950 1948 1947 1953 1951 1949 1952 1951 1952 1954 1952 1952 1954 1951 1955 1948 1953 1954 1951 1953 1957 1954 1955 1956 1955 1955 1957 1955 1956 1958 1957 1958 1959 1959 1959 1959 1962 1957 1962 1961 1961 1959 1958 1962 1960 1962 1961 1963 1962 1962 1962 1964 1963 1962 1965 1962 1965 1965 1965 1965 1966 1966 1965 1967 1967 1967 1967 1967 1967 1967 1971 1967 1972 1971 1970 1967 1971 1973 1971 1974 1974 1973 1974 1977 1971 1975 1974 1975 1975 1979 1981 1975 1978 1977 1979 1979 1977 1977 1978 1979 1983 1981 1982 1983 1981 1974 1982 1984 1985 1986 1986 1986 1984 1987 1986 1985 1987 1989 1989 1989 1988 1991 1989 1991 1990 1990 1992 1991 1993 1992 1993 1991 1993 1994 1994 1997 1996 1994 1995 1995 1996 1999 1996 1999 1997 1999 1999 1998 1995 1999 2001 1999 2002 1999 2004 2002 2005 2003 2003 2004 2005 2007 2005 2003 2007 2006 2005 2006 2011 2008 2009 2009 2011 2011 2008 2010 2009 2012 2013 2011 2013 2014 2013 2016 2014 2015 2017 2013 2014 2016 2015 2018 2017 2017 2020 2021 2021 2020 2021 2021 2022 2023 2021 2021 2022 2025 2025 2026 2027 2024 2025 2027 2027 2029 2027 2029 2028 2026 2029 2031 2029 2031 2030 2030 2031 2030 2031 2036 2031 2034 2030 2031 2035 2035 2035 2031 2031 2035 2035 2037 2038 2030 2037 2037 2037 2035 2037 2037 2037 2037 2040 2038 2037 2041 2041 2040 2041 2039 2048 2042 2048 2040 2041 2041 2039 2048 2048 2048 2048 2048 2048 2048 2048 2048 2048 2048 2048 2048 2048 2050 2048 2048 2048 2048 2050 2052 2051 2052 2054 2053 2050 2048 2050 2053 2049 2053 2053 2053 2052 2055 2055 2053 2053 2055 2056 2054 2056 2054 2055 2056 2058 2055 2057 2055 2059 2056 2057 2057 2061 2056 2059 2057 2055 2060 2057 2058 2061 2059 2061 2059 2063 2061 2060 2059 2059 2060 2061 2063 2061 2061 2061 2060 2063 2061 2063 2063 2061 2063 2065 2063 2063 2066 2063 2063 2063 2063 2063 2063 2063 2063 2068 2063 2063 2063 2063 2063 2063 2063 2065 2063 2063 2063 2066 2063 2063 2063 2065 2066 2065 2068 2061 2063 2066 2062 2067 2067 2067 2066 2066 2063 2067 2068 2069 2065 2067 2063 2063 2069 2066 2065 2069 2066 2066 2066 2068 2067 2065 2068 2055 2071 2066 2067 2068 2067 2064 2069 2067 2068 2063 2067 2067 2068 2067 2063 2068 2067 2063 2067 2068 2067 2066 2066 2067 2063 2065 2067 2063 2066 2061 2066 2062 2066 2063 2063 2063 2063 2063 2063 2066 2063 2066 2063 2066 2063 2065 2063 2063 2061 2062 2063 2062 2062 2066 2063 2061 2061 2063 2061 2062 2057 2061 2061 2063 2062 2062 2061 2059 2060 2063 2061 2060 2061 2062 2059 2061 2059 2059 2060 2059 2060 2057 2058 2057 2060 2058 2059 2053 2059 2056 2058 2056 2058 2055 2057 2056 2057 2057 2056 2054 2059 2054 2053 2054 2056 2056 2053 2053 2053 2053 2054 2054 2053 2055 2053 2048 2050 2052 2048 2049 2055 2049 2054 2049 2050 2049 2049 2051 2048 2050 2049 2048 2048 2048 2048 2048 2048 2048 2048 2048 2048 2048 2048 2048 2048 2041 2048 2039 2041 2048 2041 2048 2037 2040 2039 2039 2041 2038 2037 2037 2038 2037 2040 2039 2035 2035 2037 2036 2031 2035 2037 2037 2035 2036 2031 2036 2031 2034 2031 2034 2031 2037 2031 2031 2030 2031 2031 2030 2031 2031 2030 2031 2027 2029 2026 2028 2029 2030 2027 2029 2027 2026 2027 2025 2025 2027 2025 2023 2023 2023 2021 2023 2021 2023 2019 2020 2020 2021 2021 2018 2018 2017 2017 2021 2017 2015 2017 2016 2017 2016 2015 2016 2014 2013 2015 2011 2011 2012 2011 2010 2011 2006 2015 2009 2013 2006 2011 2009 2007 2010 2007 2007 2006 2006 2005 2004 2003 2003 2004 2002 1999 2003 2003 2003 1999 2001 1999 1999 1999 1999 1999 1999 2002 1997 1998 1997 1996 1995 1995 1995 1995 1995 1994 1993 1992 1993 1990 1994 1991 1989 1988 1989 1992 1990 1988 1989 1988 1990 1986 1987 1986 1984 1992 1984 1983 1985 1986 1986 1982 1983 1983 1981 1981 1981 1980 1982 1979 1980 1979 1978 1980 1978 1977 1977 1978 1976 1975 1973 1972 1975 1972 1973 1975 1966 1972 1972 1971 1969 1971 1967 1970 1969 1967 1970 1967 1967 1971 1969 1967 1965 1967 1966 1967 1964 1967 1965 1964 1964 1963 1960 1962 1961 1955 1966 1963 1961 1963 1962 1962 1963 1960 1959 1961 1959 1960 1958 1959 1956 1960 1957 1956 1953 1959 1956 1954 1955 1956 1954 1951 1956 1954 1951 1956 1951 1951 1951 1953 1954 1952 1950 1951 1950 1951 1951 1950 1949 1953 1950 1951 1948 1951 1949 1949 1951 1948 1951 1948 1949 1949 1950 1948 1949 1943 1956 1949 1947 1947 1949 1948 1949 1944 1947 1945 1946 1944 1949 1947 1945 1946 1947 1946 1946 1945 1943 1946 1941 1950 1942 1940 1945 1943 1942 1940 1946 1940 1945 1942 1941 1940 1942 1939 1938 1941 1940 1942 1941 1938 1940 1941 1940 1942 1939 1940 1940 1939 1941 1940 1940 1940 1943 1937 1943 1940 1939 1945 1938 1938 1939 1939 1940 1940 1938 1938 1939 1938 1935 1939 1939 1939 1938 1940 1938 1939 1938 1935 1939 1939 1941 1942 1939 1939 1935 1935 1939 1937 1941 1939 1940 1939 1939 1935 1939 1938 1939 1938 1938 1939 1935 1940 1940 1935 1939 1941 1940 1939 1938 1939 1935 1938 1941 1939 1938 1939 1943 1939 1946 1938 1942 1941 1940 1937 1943 1940 1943 1943 1941 1943 1942 1943 1941 1942 1943 1940 1939 1943 1941 1946 1942 1943 1943 1943 1945 1943 1948 1941 1946 1941 1944 1942 1943 1943 1946 1945 1945 1944 1950 1946 1944 1945 1947 1945 1947 1945 1943 1950 1947 1949 1948 1945 1949 1947 1947 1947 1946 1946 1949 1946 1949 1947 1948 1950 1951 1951 1951 1951 1952 1951 1949 1952 1950 1954 1951 1954 1951 1954 1950 1955 1953 1954 1956 1955 1954 1957 1956 1954 1959 1956 1954 1955 1957 1957 1957 1959 1956 1957 1958 1958 1957 1961 1956 1959 1960 1963 1960 1961 1964 1961 1964 1967 1963 1963 1965 1962 1963 1965 1963 1967 1964 1965 1967 1965 1963 1967 1966 1965 1967 1966 1967 1967 1967 1967 1971 1971 1971 1969 1973 1970 1971 1974 1967 1974 1974 1975 1975 1967 1977 1972 1975 1975 1977 1975 1981 1977 1976 1978 1979 1978 1979 1980 1980 1980 1977 1980 1980 1979 1982 1982 1981 1982 1983 1983 1983 1987 1981 1987 1987 1986 1984 1990 1987 1987 1987 1988 1988 1990 1987 1990 1990 1991 1991 1992 1991 1993 1991 1993 1993 1995 1994 1993 1994 1993 1997 1997 1995 1999 1995 1999 1996 1999 1999 1999 1999 1999 1999 1999 1999 2003 2003 2004 2004 2004 2002 2004 2005 2007 2006 2006 2009 2010 2007 2009 2008 2009 2008 2008 2014 2007 2012 2011 2013 2011 2011 2013 2015 2016 2015 2015 2015 2015 2007 2018 2017 2016 2017 2021 2019 2020 2020 2019 2022 2019 2021 2020 2022 2019 2026 2020 2020 2021 2023 2024 2025 2025 2024 2026 2026 2027 2026 2028 2026 2028 2028 2029 2028 2031 2030 2030 2031 2031 2039 2031 2031 2031 2031 2035 2031 2034 2037 2034 2035 2036 2035 2035 2037 2039 2035 2040 2037 2039 2037 2040 2039 2031 2027 2041 2040 2039 2039 2048 2041 2042 2038 2048 2040 2040 2040 2048 2048 2048 2048 2048 2048 2048 2040 2048 2048 2048 2048 2048 2048 2048 2048 2048 2048 2049 2048 2048 2051 2053 2050 2050 2050 2051 2050 2051 2058 2055 2051 2055 2050 2051 2054 2057 2053 2057 2053 2053 2054 2054 2057 2053 2056 2054 2055 2057 2055 2057 2051 2055 2056 2058 2059 2058 2059 2053 2058 2056 2056 2061 2058 2059 2058 2059 2061 2059 2061 2058 2058 2060 2059 2057 2061 2063 2061 2063 2062 2059 2062 2063 2060 2062 2062 2063 2061 2065 2059 2061 2059 2063 2063 2063 2063 2063 2063 2063 2063 2062 2061 2063 2063 2063 2063 2065 2066 2066 2067 2063 2067 2067 2063 2066 2072 2063 2063 2066 2067 2063 2063 2068 2067 2063 2068 2066 2063 2068 2063 2067 2067 2063 2065 2063 2065 2067 2067 2063 2068 2068 2066 2066 2066 2066 2066 2067 2066 2067 2067 2053 2070 2067 2066 2067 2068 2065 2063 2067 2066 2063 2067 2068 2066 2065 2068 2066 2066 2067 2067 2063 2068 2065 2062 2063 2063 2063 2062 2066 2077 2063 2066 2063 2067 2068 2066 2065 2063 2063 2063 2063 2066 2063 2063 2063 2063 2063 2063 2062 2063 2063 2061 2062 2063 2063 2063 2063 2060 2061 2061 2062 2054 2062 2062 2061 2061 2060 2061 2061 2060 2060 2063 2060 2061 2059 2063 2061 2059 2058 2062 2057 2057 2057 2059 2058 2057 2057 2058 2058 2057 2057 2052 2061 2056 2055 2057 2055 2055 2053 2055 2058 2057 2055 2055 2059 2054 2055 2052 2055 2052 2052 2052 2052 2054 2053 2051 2049 2050 2051 2049 2048 2048 2053 2051 2048 2049 2048 2048 2049 2048 2048 2048 2048 2043 2048 2048 2048 2048 2048 2042 2048 2048 2048 2048 2048 2048 2042 2041 2041 2041 2048 2048 2039 2048 2048 2038 2038 2037 2039 2038 2038 2040 2036 2035 2037 2035 2035 2034 2036 2036 2031 2031 2035 2031 2029 2031 2031 2031 2031 2030 2030 2025 2030 2030 2028 2029 2028 2031 2029 2028 2029 2031 2027 2028 2027 2027 2026 2027 2025 2023 2024 2025 2025 2023 2025 2023 2021 2024 2022 2022 2022 2018 2020 2020 2021 2019 2021 2017 2021 2018 2014 2018 2017 2015 2019 2017 2016 2015 2015 2014 2014 2012 2013 2011 2013 2012 2010 2010 2010 2008 2010 2015 2007 2002 2009 2007 2007 2007 2007 2008 2005 2005 2004 2004 2005 2004 2003 2003 2003 1999 2001 2002 2003 1999 1999 2001 1999 2005 1999 1999 1998 1997 1996 1997 1998 1995 1995 1997 1995 1994 1993 1996 1993 1993 1993 1994 1992 1991 1994 1991 1993 1989 1989 1990 1989 1987 1989 1990 1988 1986 1985 1985 1989 1981 1983 1983 1983 1983 1983 1981 1981 1983 1981 1980 1981 1981 1978 1978 1982 1978 1980 1978 1980 1978 1976 1976 1975 1977 1976 1974 1969 1975 1973 1973 1971 1973 1973 1969 1970 1971 1970 1967 1967 1967 1967 1967 1965 1967 1967 1966 1965 1966 1963 1964 1960 1963 1963 1966 1963 1967 1963 1962 1960 1959 1963 1961 1961 1961 1962 1958 1960 1961 1960 1961 1960 1960 1958 1958 1958 1958 1957 1958 1962 1957 1957 1954 1955 1957 1954 1957 1955 1955 1953 1956 1952 1952 1953 1950 1954 1953 1952 1951 1950 1951 1953 1949 1952


Update:

I got a sketch of the schematics from my partner

where R1 = 10kΩ, R2 = 20kΩ, Rpmax = R = 25kΩ，Rp being a 10bit digital resistor, the MCU being a STM32 chip as in the comments.


What is actually doing the ADC conversion (part number if it's an ADC chip or on-chip ADC of an MPU)? That will tell us which technology is being used and what the claimed specs are. What is the approximate frequency of the signal? Aside from the apparently missing codes it looks very noisy.

If I understand the work of my collaborator correctly, the converter is the embedded one on probably a ST7 MPU (do forgive me if I mixed something up). The board is supposed to be a sensor for powerline monitoring. so the actual frequency should be 50Hz, with minimal variation. @SpehroPefhany

The ST7 series does not appear to have any on-chip ADCs with more than 10 bits and you have numbers that take more than 12 bits to represent. What exactly is going on, and how 'raw' is that series of numbers?

Sorry about the mix-up, I asked my partner and the chip is actually STM32WB55VGY6.

I don't think we have enough information to give a definitive answer. I suggest looking directly at the ADC input pin and analog GND with a decent oscilloscope, which should rule out things like crossover distortion in the signal chain.

Check to make sure that the ADC is code complete.  Or states no missing codes in the datasheet.

Also, I've seen this when the analog power supply is inhibited, like by a poorly placed ferrite bead.  Do you have a schematic to post?

Sorry for the delay, I needed do some searching to understand the relevant notions. I can confirm the ST documentation promises code completeness, though I'm uncertain if the particular concerned piece is not compromised (for the last month some other guys have been using the platform to do experiments rather than us). I'll start to validate the observations with some mint condition copy, but this may take another week or so.

The device couples to the powerline magnetically, so there is indeed a big-ass ferrite ring involved. I'll try to get schematics from my collaborator soon.

What is the current ADC clock? Can you give it a run with a slower clock to compare the results?

One suggestion I have is that maybe the data is correct, but is being corrupted at the output. I have had this before, when I was clearing/writing over values before they have left the TX buffer. That would explain all the dodgy numbers ending in 0000. Maybe try output data with a different method and see if the problem persists?

@Jens the current clock is 100kHz, and we tried 10k, getting similar results. Sorry for the delay.
